# Lagrangian Constraint Help - why is this the answer?

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Q: a factory produces bodies & wheels for standard cars. Each car has to be fitted with one spare wheel. Total number of wheels produced is denoted by W. Number of car bodies is B.

Profit function: $$110B - 3B^2 - 2BW - 2W^2 + 140W$$

Write down the constraint.

Answer: $$lambda(5B - W)$$

**Why is this the constraint?**

Comment: The constraint should be $W=5B$, I imagine.

Comment: @copper.hat No, if you have 1 body you need 5 wheels. $B=1 \Rightarrow W=5$

Comment: @callculus: Thanks for catching that, it is what I meant to write. My point was to remove the extraneous $\lambda$ and add an equality sign to make it a constraint.

Comment: @copper.hat I understand. But it is about lagrange multiplier. I´m sure that the OP knows about it.

Comment: @callculus: It is not a constraint. You may view it as a penalty of sorts, but it is not a constraint.

Answer (score 1):

The text says that each car must be fitted with 1 spare wheel, along with the 4 wheels it would normally have. This means for every 1 body, you must have 5 wheels. So the number of wheels ($W$) is 5 times more than the number of bodies ($B$), i.e. $$W=5B$$ So the constraint is $$\lambda (5B-W)$$

Comment: This is an expression, not a constraint? Where does the $\lambda $ come from?

Comment: @copper.hat  $\lambda$=Lagrange multiplier

Comment: @callculus: I am aware of the possibility, but an expression by itself is not a constraint.

Comment: @copper.hat that would be a question of terminology. I am simply writing it in the form that the answer the OP says is correct, appears to be. The Lagrangian would then be $$L(B,W,\lambda)=\text{profit function}+\text{constraint}$$Of course, some may use the terminology you are using, which is why I also had that written in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One car must fit five wheels: four driving and one spare. Then the constraint is $W=5B$. The Lagrange function is:
$$L=profit+\lambda(5B-W).$$

Answer (score 0):

It is not an answer !!

You are given the function and a constraint with Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ and they are linked , so not yet started solving the problem and so nowhere near the answer.

Remove $\lambda $ from last line to get the constraint, viz., $ (5B-W). $  and start solving it.

EDIT1:

Or it may be a typo error for $ \lambda (B-5 W ). $

Comment: OP is not given the constraint - they are asked to find it, by using the wording from the problem. So this question is not about finding the Lagrangian and optimising. The question asks what intuition leads to getting that constraint.